# Unable to fetch and display files using snakebite

Tags: python, hadoop, snakebite

I'm trying out [`snakebite`](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite). I started the following client:

```
from snakebite.client import Client
client = Client("my.host.com", 8020, effective_user='datascientist')
```

First, I tried to list the users directory:

```
for x in client.ls(['/user/datascientist']):
    print x
```

This worked nicely and printed couple of dictionaries; one for each item in the directory. One of the items is a file `foobar.txt` which I'd like to see. To that end, I believe I should use [`Client.cat`](https://snakebite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#snakebite.client.Client.cat):

```
for cat in client.cat(['/user/datascientist/da-foobar.txt',]):
    print(cat)
    for item in cat:
        print(item)
```

However, this didn't work. I got the following error message:

```
ConnectionFailureException: Failure to connect to data node at (10.XXX.YYY.ZZZ:50010)
```

What am I doing wrongly?

BTW: using `PyWebHdfsClient` from `pywebhdfs.webhdfs` I managed to see the file by starting a client with the same address but with port 50070. I don't know whether this is relevant or not.

**Edit 1:** I also tried to use `snakebite.client.Client.text` and got the same error. I guess this is not surprising.

BTW, the file's content is `my file is this\ntest file`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a/the solution. It seems like the listing operation can be accomplished on the name-node alone. In contrast, the printing of the text file needs to access the data-nodes! By instantiating the client as follows

```
client = Client("stage-gap-namenode-2.srv.glispa.com", 8020, effective_user='datascientist', 
                use_datanode_hostname=True)
```

the `cat` operation works as it is not using the internal IP, but the hostname. I summarized a [minimal example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/drorata/25f274f4365fafd8895d8012ca9ede5d).